# ADB shell, ADB server version (31) doesn't match this client (39)

Tags: android, shell, adb

So no matter where I look I can't find a solution for this. I was able to use ADB shell yesterday, and I restarted my computer overnight and now when i try i get the error

```
> adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
> could not read ok from ADB Server
> * failed to start daemon
> error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Only solutions I have found include vysor or genymotion, neither of which I have installed. I am using windows 10 and can't make heads or tails of what to do. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but I keep getting the same message.

Comment: update your sdk platform-tool, it  may be help you. go to android studio setting --> Appearance & Behaviour --> Android SDK--> SDK tool tab in right side. and update Android SDK Platform-tools.